# How to stop intellij idea from automatically closing my packages everytime i do something

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Every time I reload the class while on debug or closing the currently running program, IDEA will close all my packages and I have to re-open the sub folders. It is so frustrating every time i have to open 5 sub folders every time it happens.

I tried editing the settings but none of them since to be the reason I know it is buried deep there somewhere

Comment: Do you mean that project tree is collapsed? What IDE version do you use?

Comment: maybe thats what it means? i believe its 2019, tell me how to fix it thank you

Comment: Do you use custom plugins, e.g. " Atlassian Clover for IDEA"? Please try to temporary disable them.